# How to write a C# app to change the channel on my Satellite STB via USB connected IR transmitter

Tags: c#, infrared

I want to write a C# app that when "button X" is clicked "signal X" is transmitted from a USB connected IR transmitter.  I've found a couple different IR transmitters at [Tira-2.1](http://www.home-electro.com/tira2.php) and [USB-UIRT](http://www.usbuirt.com/) but I'm not sure how I would go about programming the app to transmit via these devices.  To be clear.  I want my computer to send the signal based on human interaction with the application.  I don't want the computer to act on input from a remote to the computer.  I also know that the infrared MCE is not the answer, nor are any of the Microsoft IrDA*** functions, so please don't suggest these as possible answers.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is too broad. The answer will be different for each device; you should consult the manufacturers for documentatiom.

Comment: That's the point of my question.  I'm looking for any possible solutions that anyone may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, the IR transmitters needs to provide you a dll that you reference in your project. Also they need to provide some code examples of, wich frequency transmit to do the action X.
Its just theory.